# what's the difference between "revert commits" and "revert change" in magit?

Tags: magit

In the magit from spacemacs, when I press <kbd>O</kbd> on a commit, it shows several actions, two of them are "revert commit" and "revert change", what's the difference between them?

Comment: (Without being a magit expert) I'd say that reverting a change simply restores your local files to the original state, whereas reverting a commit creates a new change set that undoes the effect of a previous commit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the magit documentation, `Revert changes` does the following:

> Revert COMMIT by applying it in reverse to the worktree.
>   Prompt for a commit, defaulting to the commit at point.  If
>   the region selects multiple commits, then revert all of them,
>   without prompting.

The `git` command that it runs under the hood is `git revert --no-commit COMMIT` where `COMMIT` is the commit you selected.

As for `Revert commit(s)`:

> Revert COMMIT by creating a new commit.
>   Prompt for a commit, defaulting to the commit at point.  If
>   the region selects multiple commits, then revert all of them,
>   without prompting.

For this, the `git` command that gets run is `git revert COMMIT`.

In other words, reverting changes puts the changes from the selected commit back in the working tree for you to do what you want with (including commit again), while reverting a commit will undo the changes from the selected commit and create a new commit (i.e., a new commit where those changes have been undone).

Also, whenever you see options in a magit popup, you can hit `?` and then the key associated with an option to see the documentation for that option.